# Keras Conv2D get_weights clones a copy?

Tags: keras

Does get_weights make a deep clone copy or something?
The changes I make to the convolution kernels have no effect on the model until I call set_weights.
In the keras source get_weights is calling batch_get_values but the internals of that ore rather hard to understand.